# Minimal code for dynamically loaded Analysis Pass and Analysis Group in LLVM

Tags: llvm

If I am building a library externally from LLVM, what is the minimal code to define and properly "register" an Analysis Group and a pass which is part of that group?  How would it look if the pass depends on the results of a previous analysis?

The document on [writing an LLVM pass](http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html) has information on what to do in different scenarios, but it is spread across many sections and some of it seems to contradict the source code and comments of the latest LLVM.  I am looking for the full source code of the files required, like they give for the basic Hello World Pass.

Comment: To make it more clear, when I try to follow the instructions given in the Writing An LLVM Pass document, I get an error that "Two passes with the same argument...attempted to be registered"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure this out.  Here's the code you need.

In headers:

```
class MyAnalysis {
 public:
    static char ID;
    MyAnalysis();
    ~MyAnalysis();
}
```

In source:

```
struct MyPass : public llvm::ImmutablePass, public MyAnalysis {
    static char ID;
       MyPass() : llvm::ImmutablePass(ID) {
    }

    /// getAdjustedAnalysisPointer - This method is used when a pass implements
    /// an analysis interface through multiple inheritance.
    virtual void *getAdjustedAnalysisPointer(AnalysisID PI) {
      if (PI == &MyAnalysis::ID)
        return (MyAnalysis*)this;
      return this;
    }
};

struct UsingPass : public FunctionPass {
    static char ID;
    UsingPass() : FunctionPass(ID) {}

    void getAnalysisUsage(AnalysisUsage &AU) const {
     AU.addRequired<MyAnalysis>();
    }
    virtual bool runOnFunction(Function &F) {
    MyAnalysis& info =getAnalysis<MyAnalysis>();
        ...
        //use the analysis here
        ...
    }
}

char MyAnalysis::ID = 0;
static llvm::RegisterAnalysisGroup<MyAnalysis> P("My Super Awesome Analysis");

char MyPass::ID = 0;
static llvm::RegisterPass<MyPass> X("my-pass", "My pass which provides MyAnalysis", true, true);

//This is the line that is necessary, but for some reason is never mentioned in the 
//llvm source or documentation. This adds MyPass to the analysis group MyAnalysis. 
//Note that the "true" arguemnt to the macro makes MyPass the default implementation.
//Omit it to register other passes.
static llvm::RegisterAnalysisGroup<MyAnalysis,true> Y(X);


char UsingPass::ID = 0;
static RegisterPass<UsingPass> X("using-pass", "Some other pass that uses MyAnalysis", true, true);
```